# Clustering algorithms: HDBSCAN in R vs HDBSCAN in Python?

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

For working with exploratory data, which would be best clustering method? Currently I use HDBSCAN. Problem is that the results I get from using HDBSCAN in R is different from results obtained via HDSCBAN in Python.

R version:  https://rdrr.io/cran/largeVis/man/hdbscan.html

Link to data file for R: https://www.dropbox.com/s/731hjrj0geibi3f/test.csv?dl=0

```
test_r <- data.frame("data")
vis <- largevis::largevis(test_r)
cluster <- largevis::hdbscan(vis)
largevis::gplot(cluster,t(vis$coords), text = TRUE)
```

[image: OUTPUT of R]

Python version: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/tree/master/hdbscan

Link to data file for Python : https://www.dropbox.com/s/640elbjr1xt8q3e/test_projection.txt?dl=0

```
%pylab
import hdbscan
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyploy as plt
import pandas as pd

projection = np.loadtxt("data")
projection = projection[1:1001,:]

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=20, gen_min_span_tree=True)
clusterer.fit(projection)

palette = sns.color_palette()
cluster_colors = [sns.desaturate(palette[col], sat)
              if col >= 0 else (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) for col, sat in
              zip(clusterer.labels_, clusterer.probabilities_)]

fig = plt.scatter(panc_projection.T[0], panc_projection.T[1], c= cluster_colors)
```

[image: OUTPUT of Python]

What is the reason for difference between output of two versions and how to determine accuracy in terms of results? (i.e. number of clusters, cluster size and noise)

http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_hdbscan.html

Comment: Show an example! And try to find the original version, not reimplementations.

Comment: Added example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe just different defaults?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I think you are correct. API in python has many parameters and hyper parameters. I was able to replicate results in other data set after many trial and error of combinations. I personally feel Python API gives more control and flexibility compared to R.